# Trying to render Vue-component with data from HTTP request using Axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-component

I want to render a list of offerings with html bootstrap cards for a simple "black board". I have to use vue components and axios for the http request. I can't get it to work, as I always get

[Vue warn]: Property or method "angebote" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

What is the easiest way to list these offerings?

I have managed to get it to work using a new vue instance (first code snippet), but when I try the same thing with components I can't get it work (second code snippet). I want to use components, as i will have to do routes as well.

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        angebote: [],
        angebot: {
            id: null,
            title: null,
            modul: null,
            studiengang: null,
            user: null,
            price: null,
            description: null



        },
        config: {
            headers: {
                'content-type' : 'application/json',
                'x-apikey': 'myapi'
            }
        }
    },
```

NOT WORKING

```
Vue.component('app-angebot', {
  data: function() {
    return {
      angebote: [],

      config: {
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json',
          'x- apikey': 'myAPIkey'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.getAngebot();
  },
  methods: {
    getAngebot: function() {
      axios.get('https://angebot-5f4b.restdb.io/rest/angebot', this.config)
        .then((response) => {
          this.angebote = response.data.angebote;
        })
        .catch((response) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }

  },
  template: `             
   <div class="card h-30">
       <div class="card-body">
           <h4 class="card-title">
               <a href="angebot.html" v-if="angebote.title =!null"> {{angebote.title}}</a>
           </h4>
           <h6>{{angebote.price}}</h6>
           <p class="card-text">{{angebote.description}}</p>
       </div>
       <div class="card-footer">
           <small class="text-muted">
               Angeboten von: <a href="userO.html">{{angebote.user}}</a>
           </small>
       </div>
   </div>`
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

I would like to be able to render all the database entries with a v-for on a html page

Comment: Do you want a new card for each `angebote`?

Comment: yes I do. In the first part I can render them with <div v-for angebot in angebote></div>